# scrollToRowAtIndexPath stopped scrolling in release build but working in debug build

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a very strange case that I'd like to get your opinion on. In my app I have scrollToRowAtIndexPath so that when use tabs on the side index, it jumps to the cell. It's been working fine until around 3 months ago, the same function call does not scroll anymore in all the releases. I used the same XCode version, same code, but it stopped scrolling to the cell. And I found that if I run the app in XCode (i.e. debug release), the scrolling would work. But if I build the release, it wouldn't scroll. This is very puzzling.

I even tried to recompile the exact same app codes I had release back in March, and the old build would scroll but the re-compiled one that I did now would not scroll.

Has anyone got a similar issue like this that the release build behaves differently than the debug build. And release built at different times (old one in March, new one now) would behave differently? I had thought there could be a bug in XCode 5.1 (but it was the same version I used to compile the old release back in March and the re-compiled one yesterday). I updated to XCode 5.1.1 and it's the same issue.

I'm at a lost as this is very very strange~

Here is the code that was not changed back in March and now.

```
// Section Index Array
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{        
    NSMutableArray *charactersForSort = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *item in self.tableViewArray)
    {
        if (![charactersForSort containsObject:[[item valueForKey:@"name"] substringToIndex:1]])
        {
            [charactersForSort addObject:[[item valueForKey:@"name"] substringToIndex:1]];
        }
    }
    return charactersForSort;
}

// Section Index scrolling jump
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    BOOL found = NO;
    NSInteger b = 0;

    for (NSDictionary *item in self.tableViewArray)
    {
        if ([[[item valueForKey:@"name"] substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:title])
        {
            if (!found)
            {
                [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:b inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
                found = YES;
            }
        }
        b++;
    }
}
```

This code compiled in build releases worked before for about a year but stopped working a while ago. 
And this code ALWAYS worked when running in XCode.

**EDIT**

I now know the problem is the compiler optimization. Somehow the "Fastest, Smallest" optimization would cause this type of index scrolling to not work. I still don't understand why it worked before since I never changed the optimization setting.

Comment: Added in the code in original post, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use
`[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:newRectFrame animated:NO];`
instead of
`[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:b inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];`

Comment: Okay I'm able to replicate the problem in Debug build by setting its optimization level to be the same with the Release setting (fastest, smallest). So apparently the optimization engine somehow causes the scrolling to not work. 

At least now the problem is consistent. But still don't understand why post-optimized code will not scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. My apology as this is my own oversight.

In the "sectionForSectionIndexTitle", I didn't return any integer as I only have 2 sections in the table (first section is empty while content are all in the 2nd section). With Optimization on, I think it basically adds "return 0;" to the function. So the "scrollToRowAtIndexPath" is overwritten by the "return 0;" resulting in scrolling always scrolls back on top of the table (i.e. section 0). Since I don't want "sectionForSectionIndexTitle" to actually scroll my table, I worked around it by "return -1;" And now it's scrolling.

Still don't know why it worked 3 months ago as I didn't change any codes. Perhaps at some point I updated to XCode 5.1 (can't really remember), which optimize code a little differently.

Thanks all for your time.